# const_cast VS mutable ? any difference?

Tags: c++, constants, mutable

From my understanding , `mutable` cancels the `constness` of a variable

```
Class A {
  void foo() const {
  m_a = 5;
}
mutable int m_a;
};
```

But also `const_cast` :

```
void print (char * str)
{
  cout << str << endl;
}

int main () {
  const char * c = "this is a line";
  print ( const_cast<char *> (c) );
  return 0;
}
```

So , what changes one from the other ?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`const_cast` cannot cancel constness of an object. `const_cast` can only remove constness from an *access path* to an object. Access path is a pointer or a reference to an object. Removing the constness from the access path has absolutely no effect on the object itself.  Even if you use `const_cast` to remove the constness of the access path, that still does not necessarily give you the permission to modify the object. Whether you can do it or not still depends on the object itself. If it is const, you are not allowed to modify it and any attempts to do so will result in undefined behavior.

For example, this illustrates the intended use of `const_cast`

```
  int i = 5; // non-constant object
  const int *p = &i; // `p` is a const access path to `i`

  // Since we know that `i` is not a const, we can remove constness...
  int *q = const_cast<int *>(p);
  // ... and legally modify `i`
  *q = 10;
  // Now `i` is 10
```

The only reason the above is legal and valid is the fact that `i` is actually a *non-constant* object, and we know about it.

If the original object was really constant, then the above code would produce undefined behavior:

```
  const int j = 5; // constant object
  const int *p = &j; // `p` is a const access path to `j`

  int *q = const_cast<int *>(p); // `q` is a non-const access path to `j`
  *q = 10; // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR !!!
```

C++ language does not allow you to modify constant objects and `const_cast` is completely powerless here, regardless of how you use it.

`mutable` is a completely different thing. `mutable` creates a data filed that can be legally modified even if the containing object is declared `const`. In that sense `mutable` does allow you to modify [some designated parts of] constant objects. `const_cast`, on the other hand, can't do anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that `const_cast` can't cheat, but `mutable` is an exception to the rules.

On the first snippet `m_a` is `mutable`, and thus an exception to the rule that you can't modify data members on `const` member functions.

On the second snippet, `const_cast` tries to cheat, but really can't: while *the type* has changed, *actual modification is not allowed*: the string is truly `const`. Attempting to modify it would cause the program to exhibit undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is semantic - i. e. same generated code, same run-time results (`const`ness is a purely compile-time construct anyway), but the two constructs convey a slightly different meaning.

The idea is that you use `mutable` for variables that are in the class, but don't constitute the state of the object. The classic example is the current position in a blob object. Navigating in the blob does not count as "modifying" the blob in a way that matters. By using `mutable`, you're saying "this variable may change, but the object is still the same". You're stating that for this particular class, `const`-ness does not mean "all variables are frozen".

`const_cast`, on the other way, means that you're violating existing const correctness and hope to get away with it. Probably because you're working with a 3rd party API that does not respect `const` (e. g. an old school C-based one).

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, declaring a member variable as `mutable` makes it write-accessible from any constant method of that class without any other special syntax. `const_cast` on the other hand has to be performed whenever you want write access to an otherwise constant variable, and that variable doesn't even have to be a class member.

Unless you want to explicitly allow write access to a member variable, using `const_cast` in every case of violation of const correctness is preferred, if only to clearly state your intentions.

On a side note, const_cast can also be used to add or remove the `volatile` modifier.