# Const_cast allows to modify the constness to a path that leads to a const ?

Tags: c++, constants, const-cast

Given this code (from my last post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457953/const-cast-vs-mutable-any-difference/11458250#11458250)):

```
  const int j = 5; // constant object
  const int *p = &j; // `p` is a const access path to `j`

  int *q = const_cast<int *>(p); // `q` is a non-const access path to `j`
  *q = 10;

  cout << *q << endl;
```

The output is : `10`

Is it suppose to be this way ? I thought that this code was supposed to lead to
an undefined behavior , since `j` is a const . Am I wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: So your real question is "Is it allowed for a program with undefined behavior to output `10\n` to the console?"  and the answer is *Yes*.

Comment: You thought it led to undefined behaviour. It did. Where is the problem?

Comment: `Even though const_cast may remove constness from any pointer or reference, using the resulting pointer or reference to write to an object that was declared const invokes undefined behavior.` So it's an undefined behavior. [Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)

Comment: @Olwaro: Lovely , I won't use it in the future .

Comment: This almost identical [const_casting question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518630/const-casting-question) ask why the output is **not** changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined behavior can be anything -- it could do exactly what you want to it do, or it could destroy the universe. If possible, avoid undefined behavior since I don't really want to be destroyed just because you're too lazy to do things correctly.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

> This specifically frees the compiler to do whatever is easiest or most
>   efficient, should such a program be submitted. In general, any
>   behavior afterwards is also undefined. In particular, it is never
>   required that the compiler diagnose undefined behavior — therefore,
>   programs invoking undefined behavior may appear to compile and even
>   run without errors at first, only to fail on another system, or even
>   on another date. When an instance of undefined behavior occurs, so far
>   as the language specification is concerned anything could happen,
>   maybe nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't take much of an optimizer to realize that

```
*q = 10;
std::cout << *q;
// not use q anymore
```

Could be rewritten as

```
std::cout << 10;
```

And `q` can be removed, because now it isn't used.

After that, `p` and `j` are not used anymore either, and can be removed as well.

All this assuming *you* haven't entered any undefined behavior into your program. An assumption the compiler is allowed to make.